# SQL Query error: The multi-part identifier ... could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm sure this is obvious but I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting the error.

"Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "dbo.ProductCode.ProductCode" could not be bound."

I'm joining many tables base on the "Name" column in each table, but in this case I need to link ProductCodeReference.ProductCode to ProductCode.ProductCode and pull ProductCodeReference.ProductName based on ProductCode.Name

```
SELECT 
dbo.Servers.Name, 
dbo.ProductCodeReference.ProductName,
dbo.Enclosure.Model, 
dbo.OperatingSystem.FullOS, dbo.OperatingSystem.osbit,
dbo.OperatingSystem.ServicePack, dbo.OperatingSystem.Version,
dbo.Processor.Processors, dbo.Processor.CoreCount,
dbo.Memory.capacity,
dbo.MarcLevel.marcLevel
FROM dbo.Servers

INNER JOIN dbo.ProductCodeReference
ON dbo.ProductCode.ProductCode=dbo.ProductCodeReference.ProductCode

INNER JOIN dbo.Enclosure
ON dbo.Servers.Name=dbo.Enclosure.Name

INNER JOIN dbo.OperatingSystem
ON dbo.Servers.Name=dbo.OperatingSystem.Name

INNER JOIN dbo.Processor
ON dbo.Servers.Name=dbo.Processor.Name

INNER JOIN dbo.Memory
ON dbo.Servers.Name=dbo.Memory.name

INNER JOIN dbo.MarcLevel
ON dbo.Servers.Name=dbo.MarcLevel.name

ORDER BY dbo.Servers.Name
```

Hopefully that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Also see this if it help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120081/why-am-i-getting-a-multi-part-identifier-could-not-be-bound-error/26379769#26379769

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with the line shown below, because there is no table called `ProductCode` in the query:

```
dbo.ProductCode.ProductCode
```

It looks like you forgot to include the `ProductCode` table in your query.

```
FROM dbo.Servers  

INNER JOIN dbo.ProductCode
ON .... = ....  

INNER JOIN dbo.ProductCodeReference  
ON dbo.ProductCode.ProductCode=dbo.ProductCodeReference.ProductCode
```

Comment: That was easy. Makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: I had to wait 5 minutes to accept it, you guys responded too quickly.

Comment: That's what makes SO better than all the rest ;)

Answer (score 2):

There's no reference to a `dbo.ProductCode` table anywhere in your query except this one line:

```
ON dbo.ProductCode.ProductCode=dbo.ProductCodeReference.ProductCode
```

That table needs to be specified by a JOIN somewhere.