# Why am I getting a "Multi-part Identifier could not be bound" error?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I recently started using SSRS reports and I am struggling to understand why I am getting the following error:

```
"The multi-part identifier 'ST.ProvinceID' could not be bound".
```

I understand what the error means, but I don't understand why it's not working in this instance. I have build quite a few SQL statements in my life, but for some reason, (of which I still need to figure out), SSRS SQL reports does not always work the same way a normal SQL query would.

Here is my execution code for the SSRS report:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [P].[Title], ST.Branch_CourtName, COUNT(DISTINCT UI.ID) AS NumUsers
FROM ITS___Structural_Location_Details ST, [User_Information_Maintenance] [UI]
JOIN [Province] [P]
ON [P].[ID] = ST.ProvinceID
WHERE ST.ProvinceID = UI.Province
GROUP BY ST.Branch_CourtName
```

I have double checked all the spelling for my table and column names. If you remove the JOIN it works, but I cannot see why it would not work in this instance.

This is a quick structure of all 3 tables.

```
Province:  | ITS___Structural_Location_Details:   | User_Information_Maintenance
ID         | ID                                   | ID
Title      | ProvinceID                           | Province
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Try a `CROSS JOIN` between the tables in the from clause. Don't think you can use ansi joins and old style in the same query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the tables separately in the join statements. If I understand your query correctly then you should be able to INNER JOIN your User_Information_Maintenance table and remove the WHERE clause..

```
SELECT DISTINCT [P].[Title]
              , ST.Branch_CourtName
              , COUNT(DISTINCT UI.ID) AS NumUsers
FROM ITS___Structural_Location_Details ST
INNER JOIN [Province] [P]
   ON [P].[ID] = ST.ProvinceID
INNER JOIN [User_Information_Maintenance] [UI]
   ON UI.Province = P.ProvinceId
GROUP BY ST.Branch_CourtName
```

Comment: Hi Sam. The reason for adding it next to each other, was because of this stupid error. I did originally had it both as inner joins like you mentioned, but I tried all sorts of other ways to make the thing connect to each other, but couldn't get it to work like that.

Answer (score 0):

I also faces the same error, with one of my query, but i was using two tables in FROM clause. Then i removed one table from the query's FROM clause and used it as JOIN and error gone. hope this will help someone.